# How do I get distinct text values in a group-by while running an aggregate?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data that is populated in a slightly odd pattern, so I'm having to do a lot of subquerying to get the data formatted the way I like. It's already difficult to read, so I'm wondering if there are any Postgres functions I could utilize or simply a better way to query this.

The relevant data here is in two tables:

`observations`

```
+--------+--------+-------------+
| obs_id | person | observed_at |
+--------+--------+-------------+
| 1a     | John   | 1/1/20      |
| 2b     | Barry  | 2/1/20      |
| 3c     | John   | 3/1/20      |
| 4d     | Barry  | 4/1/20      |
| 5e     | John   | 5/1/20      |
| 6f     | Zach   | 7/1/20      |
+--------+--------+-------------+
```

`measurements`

```
+--------+---------+-------+-------+
| obs_id | meas_id | score | arc   |
+--------+---------+-------+-------+
| 1a     | f32f    | 1     | NULL  |
| 1a     | k8787   | NULL  | NULL  |
| 1a     | 93j2    | NULL  | ARC 1 |
| 1a     | 0fkd    | 2     | NULL  |
| 2b     | 92u4    | 4     | NULL  |
| 2b     | 10fl    | NULL  | ARC 1 |
| 2b     | 42u4    | 3     | NULL  |
| 3c     | 70fl    | NULL  | ARC 1 |
| 3c     | 70fl    | 4     | NULL  |
| 3c     | 8f09    | 1     | NULL  |
| 4d     | 0987    | 4     | NULL  |
| 4d     | 0192    | 4     | NULL  |
| 4d     | 1234    | NULL  | ARC 1 |
| 5e     | 8d0s    | NULL  | ARC 2 |
| 5e     | 1112    | 3     | NULL  |
| 6f     | 0981    | 1     | NULL  |
| 6f     | fdsf    | 2     | NULL  |
| 6f     | jy4s    | 3     | NULL  |
| 6f     | 876j    | NULL  | ARC 1 |
+--------+---------+-------+-------+
```

In English, this is what a record in the output should be: in EACH arc, for EACH person, calculate the LATEST observation's score. So in the output, John will have 2 records (1 row in both ARC 1 and ARC 2), Barry will have 1 record (1 in ARC 1), and Zach will also have just 1 record (1 in ARC 1).

In more technical terms, I'd like the output to be at the granularity of `person | arc | avg_score`. The part I'm having trouble with is getting the data grouped while getting the `avg(score)` and also getting the `arc`s. Here's what the output should look like:

```
+--------+--------+-----------+
| person |  arc   | avg_score |
+--------+--------+-----------+
| John   | ARC 1  | 2.5       |
| John   | ARC 2  | 3         |
| Barry  | ARC 1  | 4         |
| Zach   | ARC 1  | 2         |
+--------+--------+-----------+
```

This isn't correct, but has the general gist of what I'm trying to do. This only gets 1 record per person, but I'd like the output more granular to split per arc. I know I could do another pass and get the `avg(score)` and `min(arc)` again, but I have another 2 queries on top of this and want to minimize the # of queries.

```
SELECT
  row_number() over (partition by person order by observed_at desc) as row_num,
  *
FROM
(
SELECT
  obs_id,
  person,
  observed_at,
  avg(score),
  max(arc)
FROM observations as o
INNER JOIN measurements as m
  ON o.obs_id = m.obs_id
GROUP BY obs_id, person, observed_at
) a
```

This is a lot for asking how to reduce the # of passes on a table, but I have to do quite a few more subqueries and any fewer I can do is a win.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like that

```
with
t1l as (
    select t1.*, t2.arc, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by arc, person order by observed_at desc) n
    from observations t1
    left join measurements t2 on t1.obs_id = t2.obs_id
    where arc is not null
)
select person, t1l.arc, avg(t2.score) avg_score
from t1l
join measurements t2 on t2.obs_id = t1l.obs_id
where n=1
group by person, t1l.arc
order by person, arc
```